# why does build.gradle doesn't look like Groovy?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I read the gradle was written in groovy.
However my build.gradle file doesn't look like groovy.
Infact it doesn't look like a language at all.
Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.israelkariti.location2_1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what's up with this syntax.
How does that syntax is a Groovy code?
And if i m missing something big than please elaborate on how this thing work.
thank you

Comment: Gradle is not written in groovy. The Gradle build script is a groovy DSL. Which but are you struggling with?

Comment: I m looking at the build.gradle file of my android studio project.

Comment: Is "dependecies" a keyword in groovy DSL ?

Comment: what i m trying to understand is where can i find the rules for  this file format

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Comment: For dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: And Java projects: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

Comment: @tim_yates: Actually, thats not entirely correct. Most of Gradle is written in Java, but some parts are also written in Groovy. The Gradle GitHub repository states the following language distribution: Java 48.3%, Groovy 45.5% and C++ 4.9%.

Comment: Fair enough if you include plugins and tests. The main core is Java though https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/core/src/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Gradle adds some magic for its DSL, but technically speaking is each Gradle script fully valid Groovy.

To understand all the things like `dependencies`, `apply plugin:` and so on, we need to learn about the different types of Gradle scripts:

- Build scripts (`build.gradle`)
- Settings scripts (`settings.gradle`)
- Initialization scripts (e.g. `init.gradle`)

All these script are executed in different scopes, since they are "applied on" different objects. Gradle calls this behaviour "attaching a delegate object".

For build scripts (like the one, you asked about), this object is a [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html). Now lets analyze your Gradle script:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

The [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface extends the [`PluginAware`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html) interface, which defines an `apply` method taking a `Map<String,?>`. In Groovy, the map notation is `[key:value, ...]`, brackets can be omitted and map keys of type `String` are not written in quotes. So, `plugin: 'com.android.application'` is nothing more but a Groovy map and its handed to the `apply` method.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

I'll continue with this part and finish with the `android` part, because its easier to understand this way:

`dependencies` is not a Gradle keyword, its simply the name of a method of the already mentioned [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface. This method takes a `Closure`, which is wrapped inside the braces. Normal method call brackets are omitted again. The closure is executed on a [`DependencyHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) object. Now we just add dependencies to our configurations. We could use the `add` method and pass a configuration name and a dependency notation (and optionally a new closure).

Here starts the Gradle magic. For each existing configuration in the project's [`ConfigurationContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html), a new method with the name of the respective configuration is added to the `DependencyHandler`, so we can simply use this method instead of using `add` all the time. When developing for Java, these configurations and therefor methods are `compile`, `runtime`, `testCompile` (among others). The `fileTree` is, once again, just a method of the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    ...
}
```

The methods defined by the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface are not the only available methods. Gradle plugins (like the Android plugin you are using) can add *extensions* or *conventions*. This way, properties and methods can be called like they would belong to the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) object. This is how the `android` part can be configured via a closure right in the build script.

Inside the `android` closure, some additional Gradle magic happens. You probably know that, in Groovy, one can omit the `get` or `set` part and access properties directly (while possible getters or setters are still called). Gradle also adds a method for each property with the name of the property, which can be used as setter. This way, we can call the `compileSdkVersion` method to set the `compileSdkVersion` property. Once again, brackets are omitted. This is just some syntactic sugar, which lets us omit the assignment operator.

Whenever you start a new braces level, you basically use a closure to configure an object. Sometimes a new object is created, sometimes an existing property is used. Sometimes, you need to read the documentation to understand what's happening exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
when you say "This is just some syntactic sugar, which lets us omit the assignment operator" do you mean - omit the parentheses ?
replacing 
compileSdkVersion(25) 
with
compileSdkVersion 25

Comment: **Groovy** lets you omit all 'unneccessary' parentheses, it's a language feature. So, yes, you can thank Groovy for writing `compileSdkVersion 25` instead of `compileSdkVersion(25)`. But normally, `compileSdkVersion` is not a method, its a property, so you could assign a value to it via `compileSdkVersion = 25`. Now **Gradle** generates the mentioned method for you, it's a framework feature, just so you can omit the `=` symbol.